# I can't use Expo-av together with react-native-track-player in an Expo React Native app

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

please I want to use react-native-track-player to play audios in my app and I also need Expo-av for audio recording in the same app so I installed both libraries but when I tried to generate a development build of the app with EAS the build kept failing with this error

`Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.<class-name> found in modules jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.13.3-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.13.3) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-r2.17.2-runtime (com.github.doublesymmetry.Exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.17.2)`

but when I removed Expo-av the build was successful, which means I can't use both libraries in the project,

please what can I do because I need to record audio in the project and Expo-av seems to be the best library to record audio in Expo managed app

Or are there any other libraries I can use to record audio in a React Native Expo app

Answer (score 2):

You now can use the two libraries together.

Refer back to this: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18937

This is my `package.json`and the two work greatly together, both on ios and android.

```
    "expo": "^47.0.3",
    "expo-av": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-track-player": "^3.1.0"
```

Comment: oh really? lemme check ‍♂️‍♂️